# How to reshape data to apply linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, modeling

I have a dataframe say `df`

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:12, country = rep(letters[1:4], each = 3),
      chars = rep(c(LETTERS[24:25], "GDP"),4), year_1 = 11:22, year_2 = 31:42)

df
#   id country chars year_1 year_2
#1   1       a     X     11     31
#2   2       a     Y     12     32
#3   3       a   GDP     13     33
#4   4       b     X     14     34
#5   5       b     Y     15     35
#6   6       b   GDP     16     36
#7   7       c     X     17     37
#8   8       c     Y     18     38
#9   9       c   GDP     19     39
#10 10       d     X     20     40
#11 11       d     Y     21     41
#12 12       d   GDP     22     42
```

where

`country`  is country name

`chars` - consider them as characteristic (feature) of that country like education, employment etc. One of them is GDP of that country. So all the countries are compared on the same characteristics.

`year_1` and `year_2` are the value for that characteristic for that country in those respective years.

The goal is to build a simple linear regression model which can predict GDP of the country based on the characteristics provided (`X`, `Y` and many others).

My question is what is the best way to arrange this data so that linear regression could be build on this?

- Should I have one row per country ?
- Should I have one row per country per year ?

I tried reshaping the dataframe to make it one observation per row using

```
library(reshape2)
melt(df, id.vars = c("id","country", "chars"))
```

but I am still confused as to what is the correct approach.

Comment: Seems to me that you have __time series__ data - have a look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268721/multilinear-regression-vs-time-series) or [here](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/Teaching104/Ch14_slides.pdf)

Comment: Actually, it looks like *panel* data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want one row per observation of `y`, i.e. `GDP`. This can be done as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)

df2 <- df %>% 
  select(-id) %>% 
  gather(time, value, year_1:year_2) %>% 
  spread(chars, value) %>% 
  mutate(time = parse_number(time))
```

> ```
>   country time GDP  X  Y
> 1       a    1  13 11 12
> 2       a    2  33 31 32
> 3       b    1  16 14 15
> 4       b    2  36 34 35
> 5       c    1  19 17 18
> 6       c    2  39 37 38
> 7       d    1  22 20 21
> 8       d    2  42 40 41
> ```

Now one can fit a model of the form:

```
GDP ~ time + X + Y + country
```

with appropriate interactions, random effects or autocorrelation, however you see fit.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful and makes sense. However, what is your opinion of aggregating all the values and having only one observation per country? We can take sum/mean of all the features. Do you think it would make a bad model?

Comment: That seems like a bad idea. What if GDP goes up with X and down with Y? Then the mean may make it seem there is no predictive value of X or Y.

Comment: I mean one row per country. Number of columns would be the same (X, Y and GDP) but as there is only one row for each country, we take mean of X, Y and GDP values for that country individually.

Comment: Then you lose time. If you want to forecasting to year 3, time is probably going to be important. I generally prefer to model the problem, instead of aggregating.

Comment: yes, I agree. Thanks. I think I am going to go with this approach.